# How to plot a directed line segment (vector) given 2 points (Latitude and longitude) in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, vector-graphics

Imagine that we start from a Python list like:

```
list=[[-3.7025753,40.417016,-3.7062202, 40.4285271, 20], [5.7023456,40.221567,3.67823, 41.27236, 10]]
```

Where:

- First element is longitude of point A (Ex. in first element of the list: -3.7025753)
- Second element is latitude of point A (Ex. in first element of the list: 40.417016)
- Third element is longitude of point B (Ex. in first element of the list: -3.7062202)
- Fouth element is longitude of point B (Ex. in first element of the list: 40.4285271)
- Fifth element is a magnitude (Ex. in first element of the list: 20)

What I'm trying to obtain in Matplotlib is a plot similar to:

[image: Expected Plot]

Summarizing:

1. Plotting points is clear with plot(x, y)
2. Plotting labels also clear with Text function of Matplotlib
3. The key pending Things that I'm asking are:

- 3.1 How to plot a line in the origin dot "oriented" to the target or destiny dot?

According to first answer the function to be used shoould be:

```
 matplotlib.pyplot.arrow(x, y, dx, dy, **kwargs)
```

The point is that this function receives, apart from de x and y origing corrdinates, the delta dx and dy. In my problem point B provides me the direction of the vector and the size needs to be proportional to its magnitude. So the main question is **How I can transform data from (latitude_origin, longitude_origin, latitude_destiny, longitude_destiny, magnitude) to (x, y, dx, dy)?**. Understanding that x, y has a direct transformation from latitude and longitude origin, but what about dx and dy?

Comment: Overall a well structured question and your goal is clear. However, it is expected that you provide code of what you have tried so far. You state in your summary multiple points that are clear to you. Provide the code you have written to implement those points and show where you run into a problem.

Comment: Thaks for feedback I will focus on the main question. Topic has been updated.

Comment: The question is what units magnitude represents. In terms of Euclidean distance AB are sqrt((xb - xa)**2 + (yb - ya)**2) distance apart, which is a whole lot less than 20.

Comment: Magintude represents number of travels between A and B

Comment: Alright, say you have magnitude = 1. How long should that arrow be in terms of distance in the graph?

Comment: Having magnitude 1 , distance is not relevant if all distance follow the same magnitude. I mean it is ok 1 cm, 1 m 100 m 1 km. Later this can be adapted. What it is important for me is that a vector of magnitude 6 i 6 times freater than one of maginitude 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution:

Step 1: Calculate the angle in grades that forms the line that joins origing and destiny. Using this custom function:

```
import math

def CalcPendAng (lon1, lat1, lon2,lat2):

    if (lon2-lon1)==0:
        ang_grad=0 división por 0
    else:    
        m=(lat2-lat1) / (lon2-lon1)
        ang_rad=math.atan(m) 
        ang_grad=ang_rad* 180 / 3.14159265

    return ang_grad
```

Step 2 Calculat the destiny poit that is in the sme line that joins origin and destiny but with a distance to te origin ponit = module of teh vector we want:

```
def CalcLatLonDest (lon1, lat1,modulo, angulo_grad):

    factor_corrector= 0.0001

    lon2= lon1 + (modulo* math.cos(angulo_grad))
    lat2= lat1 + (modulo* math.sin(angulo_grad))
   
    return lon2, lat2
```